# CommandHandler is not working in Telegram bot library

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I tried to use `CommandHandler` from `python-telegram-bot==7.0.1`, however, it does not do anything that I expected.

Actually, I cannot get any state:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from __future__ import unicode_literals, division, print_function
import logging
import telegram
from telegram.ext import CommandHandler, CallbackQueryHandler, MessageHandler, ConversationHandler, RegexHandler
from telegram.ext import Updater, Filters

# Set up Updater and Dispatcher

updater = Updater(TOKEN)
updater.stop()
dispatcher = updater.dispatcher

# Add logging

logging.basicConfig(format="%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s", level=logging.WARNING)

TIME, NOTIME = range(2)


def whiteboard(bot, update):
    print(1)
    bot.sendMessage(text="Send update", chat_id=update.message.chat.id)
    bot.sendMessage(text=update.message.text, chat_id=update.message.chat.id)
    print(type(TIME))
    return TIME


def whiteboard_update(bot, update):
    print(2)
    bot.sendMessage(text=update.message.text, chat_id=update.message.chat.id)
    return TIME


def cancel(bot, update):
    print(3)
    bot.sendMessage(text=update.message.text, chat_id=update.message.chat.id)
    bot.sendMessage(text="Это не время, а что то еще...", chat_id=update.message.chat.id)
    return NOTIME


def error(bot, update, error):
    logging.critical('Update "%s" caused error "%s"' % (update, error))


def main():

    whiteboard_handler = CommandHandler("whiteboard", whiteboard)
    dispatcher.add_handler(whiteboard_handler)

    conv_handler = ConversationHandler(
        entry_points=[CommandHandler("whiteboard", whiteboard)],
        states={
            TIME: [RegexHandler('^[0-9]+:[0-5][0-9]$', whiteboard_update), CommandHandler('cancel', cancel)],
            NOTIME: [MessageHandler(Filters.text, cancel), CommandHandler('cancel', cancel)]
        },
        fallbacks=[CommandHandler('cancel', cancel)],
        )
    dispatcher.add_handler(conv_handler)

    # log all errors
    updater.dispatcher.add_error_handler(error)

    # Poll user actions

    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

So, `/whiteboard` returns what it has to, but any text and/or time (ex 1:11) does not get me to needed function.

Answer (score 0):

only the first handler of any group that can be executed is executed, the other handlers of the same group aren't.

In your case commandHandler and conversationHandler are in the same group and when the user type the command, only the commandHandler is executed and not the conversationHandler (only one handler per group is executed (if they are triggered) in the order you wrote them).

if you want to run both them you can split them in two different groups doing  this:

```
 dispatcher.add_handler(whiteboard_handler, -1)
```

adding '-1' as paramter you are saying that it belongs to a previous group of handlers.

or if you don't want split them in the two groups you can use the [flow control](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/pull/738), but it should be merged only in the master branch so far. to use it you have to raise "DispatcherHandlerContinue" exception

Comment: Thank you! Group ordering helped!